# Using Passport.SocketIO cookie parser error

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, socket.io, passport.js

I am using the following:

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.0.0",
    "socket.io": "0.9.16",
    "mongoose": "^3.8.8",
    "passport": "^0.2.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "express-session": "^1.0.3",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.0.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.0.2",
    "session-mongoose": "git://github.com/danpe/session-mongoose.git#master",
    "passport.socketio": "^3.0.1"
  }
```

Setting my socket.io authorization:

```
io.set("authorization", passportSocketIo.authorize({
    passport : passport,
    cookieParser: cookieParser(),
    key:    settings.sessionKey,  //the cookie where express (or connect) stores its session id.
    secret: settings.sessionSecret,       //the session secret to parse the cookie
    store:  sessionStore,  //the session store that express uses
    fail: function(data, accept) {
        console.log("failed");
        // console.log(data);// *optional* callbacks on success or fail
        accept(null, false);             // second param takes boolean on whether or not to allow handshake
    },
    success: function(data, accept) {
        console.log("success socket.io auth");
        // console.log(data);
        accept(null, true);
    }
}));
```

When I'm trying to connect with my client:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:3000/');
socket.on('connect', function () {
    // socket connected
    console.log("Socket Connected!");
});
```

Server crashes with the following:

```
S:\Server\node_modules\cookie-parser\index.js:27
    var cookies = req.headers.cookie;
                             ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'cookie' of undefined 
    at Object.cookieParser(S:\Server\node_modules\cookie-parser\index.js:27:30)
    at parseCookie (S:\Server\node_modules\passport.socketio\lib\index.js:4:27)
    at Manager.<anonymous> (S:\Server\node_modules\passport.socketio\lib\index.js:37:19)
    at Manager.authorize (S:\Server\node_modules\socket.io\lib\manager.js:910:31)
    at Manager.handleHandshake (S:\Server\node_modules\socket.io\lib\manager.js:786:8)
    at Manager.handleRequest (S:\Server\node_modules\socket.io\lib\manager.js:593:12)
    at Server.<anonymous> (S:\Server\node_modules\socket.io\lib\manager.js:119:10)
    at Server.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at HTTPParser.parser.onIncoming (http.js:2108:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:121:23)
```

Any ideas how this can happen ?

Comment: Express 4.x doesn't have a headers property. Headers are retrieved with req.get and cookies are on req.cookies. I'm guessing cookieParser expects the headers property so the easiest option might be to move back to express 3.x. http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.cookies

Comment: @aembke I'm using the latest CookieParser that supports express 4.x the code: `if (req.cookies) return next();` is the first line in the cookieParser

Comment: hmm, odd. so where does the req.headers line come from? whichever module tries to reference that property needs to be patched for express 4.x. it might be passport.socketio?

Comment: @aembke [cookie-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser/blob/master/index.js) **Line 27**

Comment: interesting, i'm not sure what the easiest way to fix this would be but one way or another you'll need that module to not attempt to use the headers property. if the maintainers of cookie-parser are relatively active it might be worth contacting them to patch their code for express 4.x. Otherwise maybe just patch it yourself and submit a pull request? I'm sure you're not the first or last person that would like to use cookie-parser with express 4.x.

Comment: actually, now that I look at their code it shouldn't even get to that line if you have a cookie. are you 100% sure your cookie is set while you're testing it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was a stupid mistake, I should pass the cookieParser as a library instead of a instantiated object:

```
var cookieParser= require('cookie-parser');

io.set("authorization", passportSocketIo.authorize({
    passport : passport,
    cookieParser: cookieParser,
    key:    settings.sessionKey,  //the cookie where express (or connect) stores its session id.
    secret: settings.sessionSecret,       //the session secret to parse the cookie
    store:  sessionStore,  //the session store that express uses
    fail: function(data, accept) {
        console.log("failed");
        // console.log(data);// *optional* callbacks on success or fail
        accept(null, false);             // second param takes boolean on whether or not to allow handshake
    },
    success: function(data, accept) {
        console.log("success socket.io auth");
        // console.log(data);
        accept(null, true);
    }
}));
```

Comment: Hi Danpe, BTW set is deprecated in the newest version of socket.io. use `io.use(function (socket, next) { next(); });` instead. :)

Comment: Thanks, But I'm using 0.9.16, having trouble porting 1.0.0 to support [Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/titanium/).

Answer (score 3):

Hi I got the same problem.

It's quite logic because you are passing a socket instead of a request to the cookie parser. Just pass `socket.request` to the cookie parser and it should be fixed.

Solution can be found here: https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser/issues/3#issuecomment-41443866

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')(SESSION_SECRET);    

// ### Cookie parser

// Wrapper arround Express cookie parser, so we can use the same cookie parser for socket.io.
// Parse Cookie header and populate `socket.request.cookies` with an object keyed by the cookie names.
// Uses signed cookies by passing a secret string, which assigns `socket.request.secret` so it may be used by other middleware.

function cookieParserWrapper (socket, next) {
  // request, response and callback
  cookieParser(socket.request, {}, next);
}
```

Edit:

Found an interesting module **socket.io-bundle**: https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-bundle/blob/master/lib/cookieParser.js

Besides a cookie-parser wrapper it also has a wrapper for the express-session and csurf module.

Comment: What is to be done with this wrapper? I put it in place of `cookieParser: cookieParserWrapper(),` but it gives the same error...

Comment: If you use the code above, just use `io.use(cookieParserWrapper);` without the brackets.